# Почему в компоненте не работает useSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux

Всем добрый день! Кликом запускаю `dispatch(toggleVisiblePosition(id))` и передаю id компонента.
В редьюсере настроил обработку state таким образом: в уже имеющемся стейте с помощью `state.structurePersons.some` нахожу нужный мне элемент массива и возвращаю `...state` В консоли у элемента массива state.structurePersons свойство меняется так, как мне нужно. Но в компоненте в `useSelector(store => return store)` не работает. Не понимаю, почему. Поясните, пожалуйста, как меняя элемент state в редьюсере обновлять и компонент согласно изменившемуся элементу массива?

Спасибо!`введите сюда код`

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите вытащить конкретный массив,например, постов с редакса подойдёт такое выражение.

```
const​ ​posts​ ​=​ ​useSelector​(​state​ ​=>​ ​state​.​posts​)
```

Насчёт отрисовки компонента с добавлением элемента в стейт, должна справляться эта конструкция

```
const​ ​posts​ ​=​ ​useSelector​(​state​ ​=>​ ​state​.​posts​)

<div>
  {posts.map((post) => {
    return(
      <div> {post.value} </div>
    );
  })
</div>
```

Сразу извиняюсь за возможные синтаксические ошибки пишу с телефона
Надеюсь я правильно вас понял и ответил на вопрос :)